# Shoud we use flock or the Mutex class?

Tags: php, concurrency, pthreads

For my PHP application I need a Mutex mecanism. I'm looking at flock() and Mutex Class. Some questions.

1) Mutex Class is PECL Extension. Do you think it's enough stable to run it in one production server ?

2) Flock require fopen() and fclose() functions that hits the filesystem. I think it's bad for *performances*, as I don't need any file just an unique shared identifier for my critical section. Anyway is flock is always recommended to acheive some mutual exclusion, even if you don't deal with any files ?